# Optimizing C# code fragment, ObservableCollection and AddRange

Tags: c#, silverlight, optimization, collections, profiling

i'm profiling a silverlight component wrote by someone else.
I found many hotspots and bottlenecks, now i came across this one:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

this extension method, of course, add the AddRange method to an ObservableCollection, but it's pretty intensive in calculation.
Does anyone have a better implementation, or any suggestion on how increase performance of this piece of cose?

Thank you

Comment: Since your code works, this question should be posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `Add` multiple times results in the `INotifyCollectionChanged` being raised multiple times often causing the UI to redraw itself.

While Lee's answer is technically correct that raising a `Reset` event is the correct approach once all items have been added, I have found from experience that many grid controls (for example) do not actively support the `Reset` event.

The option that is most universally supported is to modify the collection away from the `ObservableCollection` and recreate the `ObservableCollection` property itself.

In other words with your `ObservableCollection` defined as follows on your VM...

```
private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _items;
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items {
    get { return _items;}
    set 
    { 
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(()=> Items);
    }
}
```

...add your new items as follows...

```
var tempColl = _items.ToList();
tempColl.AddRange(newItems);
Items = new ObservableCollection(tempColl);
```

Another thing to bear in mind about this technique is that it is thread-safe because you can add items to the `ObservableCollection` from a background thread if you recreate the `ObservableCollection`. A normal `ObservableCollection` cannot have items added to it via the `Add` method from a non-Dispatcher thread.

Comment: Good advice, but I fear this kind of "compensating behavior" only encourages the low quality of WPF controls that are available. If the control you use doesn't correctly support the WPF bindings, raise a bug with the provider of the control, or use something that work properly.

Comment: #rantOver. I also would just point out that having setters on collections is generally to be avoided - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx. Probably would be fine in a ViewModel, but it is not nice for the next dev.

Answer (score 1):

The cost here is generally due to the change notification that is raised for each individual add. What can be preferable to do is to create a new collection implementation that is optimized for accepting ranges of data. Instead of raising change notifications for each change, and then the Binding engine processing each as single updates, you can add all the values, then raise a single event. This event can either have the *big hammer* of being a `Reset`, or you can provide the items that changed, and the index at which they changed from.

This is an example that uses a single `Reset` notification on its `AddRange` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// An implementation of <seealso cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/> that provides the ability to suppress
/// change notifications. In sub-classes that allows performing batch work and raising notifications 
/// on completion of work. Standard usage takes advantage of this feature by providing AddRange method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly Queue<PropertyChangedEventArgs> _notifications = new Queue<PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
    private readonly Queue<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> _collectionNotifications = new Queue<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>();
    private int _notificationSupressionDepth;
    #endregion

    public ObservableList()
    {
    }
    public ObservableList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        using (SupressNotifications())
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        using (SupressNotifications())
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Remove(item);
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ReplaceRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        using (SupressNotifications())
        {
            Clear();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_notificationSupressionDepth == 0)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            //We cant filter duplicate Collection change events as this will break how UI controls work. -LC
            _collectionNotifications.Enqueue(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_notificationSupressionDepth == 0)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!_notifications.Contains(e, NotifyEventComparer.Instance))
            {
                _notifications.Enqueue(e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected IDisposable QueueNotifications()
    {
        _notificationSupressionDepth++;
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
                                     {
                                         _notificationSupressionDepth--;
                                         TryNotify();
                                     });
    }

    protected IDisposable SupressNotifications()
    {
        _notificationSupressionDepth++;
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            _notificationSupressionDepth--;
        });
    }

    private void TryNotify()
    {
        if (_notificationSupressionDepth == 0)
        {
            while (_collectionNotifications.Count > 0)
            {
                var collectionNotification = _collectionNotifications.Dequeue();
                base.OnCollectionChanged(collectionNotification);
            }

            while (_notifications.Count > 0)
            {
                var notification = _notifications.Dequeue();
                base.OnPropertyChanged(notification);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding the missing `NotifyEventComparer` class and an example `Disposable.Create` method

```
public sealed class NotifyEventComparer : IEqualityComparer<PropertyChangedEventArgs>
{
    public static readonly NotifyEventComparer Instance = new NotifyEventComparer();

    bool IEqualityComparer<PropertyChangedEventArgs>.Equals(PropertyChangedEventArgs x, PropertyChangedEventArgs y)
    {
        return x.PropertyName == y.PropertyName;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<PropertyChangedEventArgs>.GetHashCode(PropertyChangedEventArgs obj)
    {
        return obj.PropertyName.GetHashCode();
    }
}

//Either use Rx to access Disposable.Create or this simple implementation will do
public static class Disposable
{
    public static IDisposable Create(Action dispose)
    {
        if (dispose == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dispose");

        return new AnonymousDisposable(dispose);
    }

    private sealed class AnonymousDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        private Action _dispose;

        public AnonymousDisposable(Action dispose)
        {
            _dispose = dispose;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var dispose = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _dispose, null);
            if (dispose != null)
            {
                dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Lee, anyway i'm getting some trouble to figure out what is NotifyEventComparer

Comment: Apologies. Updated to be complete and stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the ObservableCollection firing the PropertyChanged event each time an item is added to the collection. Preventing this event from firing while bulk-adding items is what you want to look at. Here is an elegant solution, though I have not tried this myself.

https://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/

Comment: I like this solution, it's really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the AddRange method implementation here (for List):
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, i've seen the implementation from list.cs, but it needs too many private field and too much code :D

Answer (score 0):

There is already an accepted answer in this thread, but for all who are looking for a good implementation of *ObservableRangeCollection* supporting *AddRange* and *ReplaceRange* with single CollectionChanged notification I would really recommend [this piece of code written by James Montemagno](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/release-1.3.0/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs).